# Scrolling issue on position fixed element on iOS

Tags: ios, css, scroll, css-position, fixed

I am bulding a mobile project which has a number of modules having elements positioned as fixed. The issue which am facing is only on browsers running on iOS. 
The exact issue is that whenever I tr to scroll over the body of the page having , say the bottom toolbar, as fixed, the whole fixed element moves respectively with the scroll, and once the scroll ends completely, then only it comes back to its assigned place.

I have given the body of the page a relative css rule.
 Please help as this happens only on iOS.

```
 .add-to-block {
    background: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    *(inner content element) {
        inner content element styling...
     }
}
```

Comment: Could you fix it? I have the same problem working with Ionic 2 in 2017. In Android my navbar works fine, but in IOS it moves with the scroll and when it stops, it returns to its position.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/2otaHxz I created this bounty. I have the same issue. I have fixed elements (Hafebar, Red John and so on) these are scrolling in the Y Axis with transform (so i can't use the post below) and are fixed in the X axis with position fixed. When scrolling X fast the fixed elements (Hafebar, Red John and so on) move with the scroll and go back to the original position when i stop scrolling.

Comment: I got the same problem once, I just remove the fixed element out of scroll able div, which fixed my problem you can try that too if it's possible in your case. Hope it helps

Answer (score 13):

Please try this, source [here](https://stanko.github.io/ios-safari-scroll-position-fixed/)

```
.add-to-block {
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

Comment: it save me lot of time.

Answer (score 3):

There is not really an easy answer to this as it has been a known issue on ios for a while (supposedly fixed in ios8) but this gives you a few ways to fix it: https://remysharp.com/2012/05/24/issues-with-position-fixed-scrolling-on-ios it details all the issues with position fixed on ios devices and possible ways to fix it if you need to use it.

Answer (score 3):

Add `height: 100%` and `overflow: auto` for `fixed` element.

Full example at https://codepen.io/astnt/pen/ExgOqeX

Answer (score 2):

Safari allows you to scroll beyond the limits of the fixed div so that it can put in a nice bouncy effect. When you scroll past this point though, if there is a container that is scrollable, then subsequent touch events get handed off to this. Therefore scrolling does nothing for a bit until control gets handed back to the fixed div.

The fix is to give the container div the `overflow-y: hidden` style so that Safari does not hand off the touches, and we continue interacting with the fixed div.

Answer (score 0):

None of the proposed solutions worked for me, although i had the fixed element inside the scrolling div (and moved it up), had no transform or other layer-creating properties on the parent elements (and created a layer on the fixed element) etc.

**My solution was to just change the fixed element to be `position: sticky;`**